# ios NSPredicate to find nearest value in NSDictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsdictionary, nspredicate

I have an **array of dictionaries** like this:

```
(
{ key = 1, value = 40},
{ key = 4, value = 50},
{ key = 8, value = 60}
}
```

These are like this, 
`for >=1` *item cost is 40*,
`for >=4` *item cost is 50* and like wise.

I would like to get the value for 5, which in this case is 50.

The piece of code I have tried is:

```
NSMutableArray *wallpaperPriceArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init]; // Assuming this has all the dictionary values 

float wallpaperPriceValue = 0;

int itemNumber = 0;

for (int i = 0; i<wallpaperPriceArray.count; i++) {

int check = 0;

if(itemNumber >= [[wallpaperPriceArray objectAtIndex:i] intValue])
{
    wallpaperPriceValue = [[[wallpaperPriceArray objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"value"] floatValue];
    check++;
}

if(i + 1 <= wallpaperPriceArray.count)
{
    if(itemNumber >= [[wallpaperPriceArray objectAtIndex:i+1] intValue] && itemNumber < [[wallpaperPriceArray objectAtIndex:i+1] intValue])
    {
        wallpaperPriceValue = [[[wallpaperPriceArray objectAtIndex:i+1] objectForKey:@"value"] floatValue];
        check++;

        if(check == 2)
        {
            break ;
        }
    }
}

if(i + 2 <= wallpaperPriceArray.count)
{
    if(itemNumber >= [[wallpaperPriceArray objectAtIndex:i+2] intValue] && itemNumber < [[wallpaperPriceArray objectAtIndex:i+2] intValue])
    {
        wallpaperPriceValue = [[[wallpaperPriceArray objectAtIndex:i+2] objectForKey:@"value"] floatValue];
        check++;

        if(check == 2)
        {
            break ;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: where is your attempted code?

Comment: Plz look at the attempted code\

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I Don't think the predicate is the right thing, Better would be to enumerate the objects here is some sample code:

```
NSArray *array = @[
                   @{ @"key" : @(1), @"value" : @(40)},
                   @{ @"key" : @(4), @"value" : @(50)},
                   @{ @"key" : @(8), @"value" : @(60)}
];

NSInteger searchedValue = 5; // <---

__block NSDictionary *closestDict = nil;
__block NSInteger closestValue = 0;


[array enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    NSDictionary *dict = obj;
    NSInteger key = [dict[@"key"] integerValue];

    // Check if we got better result
    if(closestDict == nil || (key > closestValue && key <= searchedValue)){
        closestDict = dict;
        closestValue = key;

        if(key == searchedValue) { *stop = YES; }
    }
}];

NSLog(@"value %@", closestDict);
```

Comment: Your welcomed, I will be finally able to up-vote answers i like ;)

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest in addition to above answer to use the spline method to get the value needed, this is in the link 
https://github.com/soffes/SAMCubicSpline

Using this library would solve the question as follows:

```
NSArray *array = @[
               @{ @"key" : @(1), @"value" : @(40)},
               @{ @"key" : @(4), @"value" : @(50)},
               @{ @"key" : @(8), @"value" : @(60)}];

SAMCubicSpline *spline = [[SAMCubicSpline alloc]    initWithPoints:@[


[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(1.0f, 40.0f)],
  [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(4.0f, 50f)],


 [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(8.0f, 60.0f)],
]];
```

then you can obtain any value by this

```
CGFloat y = [spline interpolate:x];
```